# Copy all the values from table1 to table2 only if condition met

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say `var_Environment = QA1,QA2`.

I have two tables table 1 and table 2. Table 1 has some column name var_Environment =QA1; where as table 2 does have the same column name but no values

Now my task is, I need to copy all the values from table1 to table2 only if condition meets var_Environment =QA2  How will I perform this operation ? Can I use `Union All` with some condition? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` like below.

The `WHERE` clause may need adjustment, so run the the `SELECT` query by itself to check if the correct rows are selected.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT var_Environment 
FROM Table1
WHERE var_Environment  LIKE '%QA2%'
```